# When to use "прекрасный" and when to use "красивый"?

Tags: выбор-слова

> прекрасный вечер
>
> прекрасная девушка
>
> красивый пейзаж

I wonder if the choice depends on what noun follows?

Comment: Roughly speaking, "красивый" = "beautiful" and "прекрасный" = "wonderful".

Answer (score 9):

**Красивый** is more about appearance of things, good look, **прекрасный** is about the spirit of things, the impression they inspire and feelings they evoke, their inner virtues, their effectiveness...

А woman can be **НEкрасивая** but **прекрасная**... **Прекрасный вечер** is about how it makes you feel, **красивый вечер** is about how the surroundings look.
This is the rule of thumb but there's a degree of overlap and interchangeability between them as well and probably there're some stable collocations where certain adjective is more idiomatic.

Аt the same time **красивый** & **прекрасный пейзаж** both mean more or less the same thing referring to the appearance with difference in degree of external beauty which is greater with **прекрасный**. Speaking however of a painting, **прекрасный** will rather refer to the workmanship and artistry of the painter, where beautiful is the work itself and not the depicted scenery. In this sense **прекрасный** means *great*.

Both words are cognates of each other having **крас** as their root. **Красный** in its archaic meaning and **красивый** are synonyms ([красный угол](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB), Красная площадь, красна девица). And in **прекрасный** the quality denoted by the root **крас** is amplified with the prefix **пре-** which means beyond, over. So literally **прекрасный** is simply *more beautiful*, *more good looking*.